# SQL query with two tables, count and more info

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm just learning this stuff and I'm having trouble with this one. I have two tables, `STUDENTS` and `ADVISORS`. The students are assigned advisors within the students table using a foreign key attached to the primary key of the advisors table.

The task here is this: Provide a list of all advisors and the number of active students assigned to each. Filter out any advisors with more than 1 student.

The current script is listed below:

```
select 
    Students.AdvisorID, count(Students.AdvisorID) as 'TotalStudents'
from 
    Students 
left outer join 
    Advisors on Students.AdvisorID = Advisors.AdvisorID 
where 
    Students.IsActive = 1 
Group by 
    Students.AdvisorID 
Having 
    count(Students.AdvisorID) < 2
```

This will output a proper list showing only the `advisorID` and total students.

I need to also display the

```
Advisors.FirstName + ' ' + Advisors.LastName as 'AdvisorName'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***

[students table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNgkA.png)
[advisors table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAKdU.png)

Comment: can you add both table strucure

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's also helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For the clarification, this is running SQL 2016 Express. I will do better with my next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your original attempt is on the right track, but you need to join again to the `Advisors` table to pull in the first and last name for each adviser.  The reason for this is that after doing the aggregation all that remains is an ID for each adviser and a student count.

```
SELECT t1.AdvisorID,
       t2.TotalStudents,
       t1.FirstName + ' ' + t1.LastName AS AdvisorName
FROM Advisors t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.AdvisorID, COUNT(*) AS TotalStudents
    FROM Advisors a
    LEFT JOIN Students s
        ON a.AdvisorID = s.AdvisorID
    GROUP BY a.AdvisorID
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
) t2
    ON t1.AdvisorID = t2.AdvisorID
```

**Other notes:**

I chose to `LEFT JOIN` advisers to students, not the other way around, since you want a statistic for each adviser.  Doing the join as you first had it could filter out advisers who do not match to any student.  This is not the behavior you want, since an adviser who does not match to any student should have a student count of zero.

Comment: Ahh. Excellent point on the left join bit. You're correct in that I do want to see all advisors with less than 2 students, including those with zero. Awesome catch!

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to get what I was looking for based off your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little sample data to work with

```
USE tempdb
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.Advisors') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Advisors;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.Students') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Students;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Advisors (AdvisorID int primary key, AdvisorName varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE dbo.Students 
(
  studentID int identity primary key, 
  AdvisorID int foreign key references dbo.Advisors(AdvisorID)
);

INSERT dbo.Advisors VALUES (1, 'Mr. White'),(2,'Walter Jr.'),(3,'Mr. Pinkman');

INSERT dbo.Students (AdvisorID)
SELECT TOP (20) abs(checksum(newid())%3)+1 FROM sys.all_columns;
```

No Left Join needed, I think this will give you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT a.AdvisorID, total_students = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Advisors a
INNER JOIN dbo.Students s ON a.AdvisorID = s.AdvisorID
GROUP BY a.AdvisorID
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2;
```